# Exponential decay estimate involving $C_{0}$-semigroup and the principle eigenvalue

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, semigroup-of-operators

Consider the heat equation defined as

$$\begin{cases}
\partial_{t}u(x,t)=\Delta_{x}u(x,t) &\mbox{ } t>0\mbox{, } u\in U \\ u(x,t)=0 &\mbox{ } t\ge 0\mbox{, } x\in\partial U \\ u(x,0)=g(x) &\mbox{ } x\in U
\end{cases}$$

posed on a bounded connected open subset $U\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}$ that has a $C^{2}$-smooth boundary $\partial U$.

We know that $\exists$ a $C_{0}$-semigroup $(T(t))_{t\ge 0}$ on $L^{2}(U)$ generated by the linear operator

$$A:D(A)=H^{1}_{0}(U)\cap H^{2}(U)\to L^{2}(U) \mbox{, with } Au=\Delta u.$$

Let $\lambda_{1}>0$ be the principle eigenvalue of $-\Delta$ on $U$ with zero boundary conditions. I want to show that

$$\|T(t)\|_{\mathcal{L}(L^{2}(U),L^{2}(U))}\le e^{-\lambda_{1}t}$$

We know $\lambda_{1}=\min{\{B[u,u]|u\in H^{1}_{0}(U), \|u\|_{L^{2}(U)}=1\}}$, and from Rayleigh's formula, we have

$$\lambda_{1}=\min_{\substack{u\in H^{1}_{0}(U) \\ u\neq 0}}\frac{B[u,u]}{\|u\|^{2}_{L^{2}(U)}}$$

How do I tackle the problem from here? I assume I must exploit the semigroup property somehow.

Comment: Do you have the result about completeness of the Dirichlet eigenfunctions already? (That would provide an overkill approach to this problem).

Comment: @Ian No, I have not actually seen 'Dirichlet eigenfunctions'. I am working from Evans' 'Partial Differential Equations' book and it doesn't appear to be mentioned in there.

Comment: @user3482534 are you sure? should be in chapter 6 on elliptic PDEs, Dirichlet eigenfunction satisfy $-\Delta u=\lambda u$ with homogeneous Dirichlet boundary conditions.

Comment: @ellya Would you be able to give me a page number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because $(\Delta f,f) \le -\lambda_1\|f\|^{2}$ for $f\in\mathcal{D}(-\Delta)$, then
\begin{align}
   \frac{d}{dt}\|T(t)f\|^{2}& =(\Delta T(t)f,T(t)f)+(T(t)f,\Delta T(t)f) \\
    & \le -2\lambda_1(T(t)f,T(t)f)= -2\lambda_1\|T(t)f\|^{2},\;\; f \in\mathcal{D}(-\Delta)
\end{align}
Hence,
$$
             \frac{d}{dt}\left( e^{2\lambda_1 t}\|T(t)f\|^{2}\right) \le 0\\
                  \|T(t)f\|^{2} \le e^{-2\lambda_1 t}\|T(0)f\|^{2} \\
                        \|T(t)f\| \le e^{-\lambda_1 t}\|f\|.
$$
This easily extends to all $f$ because $\mathcal{D}(\Delta)$ is dense.

Comment: Could you explain to me how you derived $(\Delta f, f)\le -\lambda_{1}\|f\|^{2}$ for $f\in D(-\Delta)$?

Comment: If $A$ is selfadjoint with minimum spectral element $\lambda_1$, then $(Ax,x) \ge \lambda_(x,x)$. In your case, $-\Delta$ has minimum spectral element $\lambda_1$. So $\lambda_1(f,f) \le (-\Delta f,f)$.

Comment: I cannot find the definition of a 'minimum spectral element'...Is it simply an implication of the fact that $\lambda_{1}$ is the principle eigenvalue of $-\Delta$?

Comment: @user3482534 : $\inf\{ \lambda : \lambda\in\sigma(-\Delta)\}$. The inf is always a member of the spectrum because the spectrum is always closed.

Comment: $$
             \frac{d}{dt}\left( e^{2\lambda_1 t}\|T(t)f\|^{2}\right) \le 0\\
                  \|T(t)f\|^{2} \le e^{-2\lambda_1 t}\|T(0)f\|^{2} 
$$

I don't understand the step between these two inequalities.

Comment: @user3482534 : If you have a continuously differentiable function $F(t) \ge 0$ on $[0,\infty)$ and $F'(t) \le 0$, then $0 \le F(t) \le F(0)$ for all $t \ge 0$.